# Break a while loop with a push button (AccelStepper.h)

Tags: button, stepper, loop

Disclaimer: This is my first Arduino project.

**Background**: I am building a "rapunzel tower" lantern for my daughter: the witch pays a visit to Rapunzel meanwhile my daughter can read a book (or still play a bit) before going to sleep.

**Goal**:If a button is pushed --> a stepper motor turns on *and* my daughter's lantern switches on (via a relay) --> the stepper motor spins to the left (+/- 5 minutes) to bring the witch to the tower--> a led in the tower room switches on and off (+/- 1 minute) --> the stepper motor spins to the right (+/- 5 minutes) to bring the witch down *and* the lantern switches off (and my daughter needs my sleep).

**Issue** If my daughter want to sleep *before* the witch gets down, she must be able to turn off the lantern while the witch is still on the move (up or down). However, I am unable to do so. That is, I am unable to break the while function when the button is pushed to turn off the latern.

**Code**
Right now, I use the following piece of code below (compiled from different sources).

I know that I use the delay function instead of the millis function, but that is for my next step. The same goes for the time the motor spins (which I still need to tweak).

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

```
/* Example sketch to control a 28BYJ-48 stepper motor with ULN2003 driver board, AccelStepper and Arduino UNO: continuous rotation. More info: https://www.makerguides.com */
// Include the AccelStepper library:
#include <AccelStepper.h>
// Motor pin definitions:
#define motorPin1  3    // IN1 on the ULN2003 driver
#define motorPin2  4    // IN2 on the ULN2003 driver
#define motorPin3  5    // IN3 on the ULN2003 driver
#define motorPin4  6    // IN4 on the ULN2003 driver
// Define the AccelStepper interface type; 4 wire motor in half step mode:
#define MotorInterfaceType 8
// Initialize with pin sequence IN1-IN3-IN2-IN4 for using the AccelStepper library with 28BYJ-48 stepper motor:
AccelStepper stepper = AccelStepper(MotorInterfaceType, motorPin1, motorPin3, motorPin2, motorPin4);

// Code to trigger the light and motor
const int buttonPin = 1;   // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  7;     // the number of the LED pin

int relayPin = 2;          // Connected to relay
int buttonState = 0;       // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
  // Set the maximum steps per second:
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
}
void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  Serial.println(buttonState);

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
    // Let the witch go up.
      // Set the current position to 0:
      stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
      // Run the motor forward at 500 steps/second until the motor reaches 4096 steps (1 revolution):
      while (stepper.currentPosition() != 8096) {
          stepper.setSpeed(500);
          stepper.runSpeed();
      }

    // Let the witch the light turn on and off in Rapunzel's room
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

    // Let the witch let climb down.
      // Reset the position to 0:
      stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
      // Run the motor backwards at 1000 steps/second until the motor reaches -4096 steps (1 revolution):
      while (stepper.currentPosition() != -8096) {
        stepper.setSpeed(-1000);
        stepper.runSpeed();
      }
  }
  delay(5);
}
```

Comment: `while (stepper.currentPosition() != 8096) {` is a loop that repeats many times ... you can check for a button press inside that loop .... btw, the `stepper.setSpeed(500);` should be outside of the loop

Comment: You can put a read for the button inside the while loop, but a better solution would be to get rid of the while loop entirely and let the loop function do the looping.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to get rid of the loop asap and come back to you... putting the button in the while loop did not work (the push event is registered [the led on the arduino blinks when the button is pushed and the while loop paused, but when the button is released the stepper continues instead of stopping).

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks for the advice.